# PHP convert json data to php array using json_decode

Tags: php, json

I insert data using `json_decode` to MySQL database like this:

```
["kevin","rode","shure"]
```

Now I need to convert using `json_decode` to php array like this:

```
$selected = array( 'kevin', 'rode', 'shure' );
```

how do can I convert this?

Comment: use json_decode() and decode the array... your question itself has answer

Comment: You can refer [json_decode here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) @NewCod3r

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
$encoded = '["kevin","rode","shure"]';
$decoded = json_decode($encoded);// or directly pass the value here
print_r($decoded);
```

And you should get back the encoded array

Answer (score 0):

use json_decode with true param to force array output :

```
$selected = json_decode('["kevin","rode","shure"]', true);
```

NB : don't forget quotes and see documentation  http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: no need for the `true` param here, the JSON string is a numerically indexed array, `true` is only to prevent objects (assoc arrays) from being converted to `stdClass` instances

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem:with true and without I see this error:` Notice: Array to string conversion`

Comment: @NewCod3r: probably because you've forgotten the quotes around the alleged JSON string (`['foo', 'bar']` is valid PHP, too). Removing the true doesn' t brake anything [see example](https://eval.in/430007)

Comment: Yes but if he will use json_decode in futur with object and he wants to get an array he will not understand why , so add true param and ensure of array type output =)

Answer (score 0):

Convert de data in a string, or get from $_GET or $_POST, it depends of you

```
$data = '["kevin","rode","shure"]';

$data = json_decode($data);

foreach($data as $name){
    echo $name . "<br />";
}
```

and beware of double quotes